# Pass down a generic key of object from one type to another type

Tags: typescript

I have these two objects, where one object act as template for the other. I want to map form values object to an api request object. I'm not concerned about the implementation, but rather typing it with typescript.

I have trouble typing the GetFormValueType and the ValueType.

Here's some dummy code:

```js
type FormType = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string
}

type ApiRequestType = {
  example: string,
  another_example: string
}

type GetFormValueType = unknown
const getFormValue:GetFormValueType = (fieldName, transformer) => form => transformer ? transformer(form[fieldName]) : form[fieldName]
const ValueType = unknown
const FORM_TO_API_REQUEST_MAP:Record<ApiRequestType, ValueType> = {
  example: getFormValue('foo', transform),
  another_example: getFormValue('bar', transform)
}

const formData:FormType = {
 foo: 'hello',
 bar: 'world'
}

const apiRequest:ApiRequestType = Object.entries(FORM_TO_API_REQUEST_MAP).reduce((request, [apiRequestKey, handler]) => ({
  ...request,
  [apiRequestKey]: FORM_TO_API_REQUEST_MAP[apiRequestKey](formData)
}), {} as ApiRequestType)
```

This is how far I got:

```js
type ValueType = value: ?? how to know the type of the value (FormType[T]) => ?? (how to know the api request key type?)
type GetFormValueType = <T extends keyof FormType>(fieldName: T, transformer:ValueType) => (form:FormType) => ReturnType<TransformerType> | FormType[T]
```

I don't quite understand how to pass down generics to one type (GetFormValueType) to another (ValueType). At least I think thats the issue.

Comment: Please share `transform` function. Make sure your example is reproducable

Comment: I must say I don't really understand :( Maybe you can post runnable code at something like https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: I've made an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9hkkxh?file=index.ts

Im trying to type ValueType and TransformerType. They should infer the type of the form value given the fieldName (generic T) and FormType, and the api request type, so I cant for example add a transform method to 'another_example' which returns a string, because 'another_example' expects a number. Or another way around, pass a formValue of a string to a transformer that expect its argument to be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is not 100% equivalent, as I'm not sure how to make `transformer` optional. In this solution I use `id` function as a default.

```js
type FormType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  x: number;
};

type ApiRequestType = {
  example: string;
  another_example: string;
  x: string;
};

type ValueTransformer<T, T1> = (value: T) => T1;

type FormValueType<FormModel, Result> = (formValue: FormModel) => Result;

// Here we use generic parameters for both model and key.
type GetFormValueType<FormModel> = <Key extends keyof FormModel, Result>(
  fieldName: Key,
  transformer: ValueTransformer<FormModel[Key], Result>
) => FormValueType<FormModel, Result>;

const id = <T>(x: T) => x;

const numberToString = (x: number) => String(x);

const getFormValue: GetFormValueType<FormType> =
  (fieldName, transformer) => (form) =>
    transformer(form[fieldName]);


// Here we need to use typescript mapped types instead of just record.
type RequestMap<From, To> = {
  [Key in keyof To]: FormValueType<From, To[Key]>;
};

const FORM_TO_API_REQUEST_MAP: RequestMap<FormType, ApiRequestType> = {
  example: getFormValue("foo", id),
  another_example: getFormValue("bar", id),
  x: getFormValue("x", numberToString),
};

const formData: FormType = {
  foo: "hello",
  bar: "world",
  x: 10,
};

const apiRequest: ApiRequestType = Object.entries(
  FORM_TO_API_REQUEST_MAP
).reduce(
  (request, [apiRequestKey, handler]) => ({
    ...request,
    [apiRequestKey]: FORM_TO_API_REQUEST_MAP[apiRequestKey](formData),
  }),
  {} as ApiRequestType
);
```

Comment: Awesome! Indeed you are very close except for the conditional transformer. I think I can work around that in the reducer.